# what are the commonly used architectures for web applications?

Tags: web-applications, architecture

I have been developing applications that have a three-tier architecture and mostly using MVC frameworks. What are other architectures that are used if any?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another commonly used arhitecture is an event driven, or a component oriented one.

It is a bit difficult to define it precisely, but think of it as a "desktop way" of writing web applications. Events are usually invoked via callbacks, and views are composed using existing components. All of this boils down to: writing web apps is a bit easier, but you have less control over what is being done in the background when compared with MVC style architecture.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/100001/mvc-or-event-driven-component-oriented-web-frameworks) is one SO post dealing with this very comparison. Googling will reveal you more.

Answer (score 0):

another good example is MVP - Model View Presenter

more information and also videos can be found on this pattern on their [wiki](http://wiki.webformsmvp.com/index.php?title=Documentation)